# Whats SQL Server NVARCHAR(max) equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, varchar, sql-variant-property

Using SQL Server you just have to give the "MAX" parameter to the length of a text data type, but in MySQL there's no such a thing.

According to [Ispirer](http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/nvarchar_n):

> "n" is the maximum number of characters, optional
>
> Range:    1 ⇐ n ⇐ 21845 (65535 bytes is the maximum row size shared among all columns)

Does it mean that:

```
[SQL Server] "NVARCHAR(MAX)" == [MySQL]"NVARCHAR(N)"
```

Or do i have to say `NVARCHAR(21845)` as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in MySQL?

Answer (score 11):

According to this MySQL document the LONGTEXT datatype in MySQL is 4 Gigabytes.

http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/mysql/data-types/longtext

Note that the number of characters depends on the encoding.

Comment: Is Longtext better than NVARCHAR to store text as html or xml?

Comment: I would not think so. But why the question? If you are using MySQL then use LONGTEXT, but if you are using MS SQL Server then use VARCHAR (MAX). I would not choose the server platform based on this issue, but would choose to stick to my current environment unless there was real reason to change.

Answer (score 3):

TEXT (max of 64K bytes) or MEDIUMTEXT (max 16M bytes) is typically used.  There is no 'max' after them.

VARCHAR(1111) is like NVARCHAR; the 1111 is the limit on *characters* (not *bytes*).  VARCHAR is limited to 64K characters.